# Strange DLL loading behavior in Powershell 7

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I've managed to boil down my test to a simple command:

```
PS C:\Users\CpUser> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\CpUser\.nuget\packages\njsonschema\10.4.0\lib\net45\NJsonSchema.dll")
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'NJsonSchema, Version=10.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c2f9c3bdfae56102'."
```

I'm using 64-bit Powershell v7.1.3 on Windows 10. Ran as administrator. It's not able to load the DLL I gave it, which is very odd to me. It also does not give me any detail as to why it cannot load it. When I try a lower version of `NJsonSchema.dll`, it works, but it loads it from an unexpected location:

```
PS C:\Users\CpUser> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Users\CpUser\.nuget\packages\njsonschema\9.10.52\lib\net45\NJsonSchema.dll")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\NJsonSchema.dll
```

It's loading it from `C:\Program Files\Powershell\7` which seems wrong to me. I sent to the Properties -> Details of that DLL and it says it is version `10.2.2`. What it *seems* like is happening here is:

1. Powershell takes the version of the assembly I provided in the `LoadFrom()` call
2. It searches `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7` for the same DLL with a version *equal to or greater than* the version obtained in the previous step
3. If not found, fail.

What I expect is for it to load the DLL using the absolute path I gave it.

As a workaround, I found another solution that does seem to work:

```
$AssemblyPath = "C:\Users\CpUser\.nuget\packages\njsonschema\10.4.0\lib\net45\NJsonSchema.dll"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($AssemblyPath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
```

I get a successful result when I run the above in a script:

```
PS C:\Users\CpUser> .\testLoadDll.ps1

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319
```

So I feel like this rules out any issues with the DLL itself. I'm completely lost here. Can someone explain the behavior I'm seeing and how to get the behavior I expect?

Comment: *It does not give me any details why it cannot load it*  Try turning on [assembly binding failure logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, for [Assembly.LoadFrom Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-5.0)

> The LoadFrom method has the following disadvantages. Consider using
> [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=net-5.0) instead.
>
> ```
>                  ...
> ```
>
> If an assembly is loaded with LoadFrom, and the probing path includes
> an assembly with the same identity but a different location, an
> InvalidCastException, MissingMethodException, or other unexpected
> behavior can occur.

**Update**:

According to [Resolving PowerShell module assembly dependency conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/resolving-dependency-conflicts?view=powershell-7.1),

> PowerShell and .NET
>
> PowerShell runs on the .NET platform. NET is ultimately responsible
> for resolving and loading assembly dependencies, so we must understand
> how .NET operates here to understand dependency conflicts.
>
> We must also confront the fact that different versions of PowerShell
> run on different .NET implementations. In general, PowerShell 5.1 and
> below run on .NET Framework, while PowerShell 6 and above run on .NET
> Core. These two implementations of .NET load and handle assemblies
> differently. This means that resolving dependency conflicts can vary
> depending on the underlying .NET platform.

Therefore, ensure you are loading the DLL in the `netstandard2.0` folder, if using Powershell version 6 and above.

Try the following:

Open PowerShell version 7.1.3:

- In "Type here to search" box, enter `pwsh`
- Right-click `PowerShell 7 (x64)`
- Select `Run as administrator`

**Get PowerShell version**:

```
Get-Host | Select-Object Version
```

[image]

**Get Loaded Assemblies**:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

**Load NJsonSchema.dll**:

**Note**: Since we're using PowerShell 7.x.x, use the NJsonSchema.dll file in the `netstandard2.0` folder.

```
$Assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Loadfile('C:\Users\CpUser\.nuget\packages\njsonschema\10.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\NJsonSchema.dll')
```

**Get Loaded Assemblies** (again):

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

[image]

**Check the version of NJsonSchema.dll**:

```
$Assembly.GetName()
```

[image]

Comment: I set `$env:PATH` and `$env:PSModulePath` to a single directory (the location of the DLL I'm loading) and it *STILL* fails. When I call `Load("NJsonSchema")`, it *still* loads it from the Program Files location. This is driving me nuts.